# python layout/functionality questions

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am about to start making a python (2.7) app - using wx, but im still having a few theoretical walls infront, making me sceptical about practical success.

So below are a few questions:
1) My app will have many widgets (buttons, entries, labels, comboboxes) - where the majority will be added when the user invokes some events (clicking Add button will create additional labels, entries, comboboxes and buttons). My question here is, how can i keep track of this dynamic content, i sure wish to have a delete option aswell. My best guess was lists, but im still not sure how can i handle something like a combobox + im kinda lost on how could i delete a group of widgets.

2) which practice of widget placement would be best for a fixed size frame/panels? Would be manual setting of xypos be just fine? Even considering my questions in 1) - mainly interested how to handle layout if something in the middle of frame gets deleted - holes would not be nice.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would learn sizers if you're going to adding and removing widgets. If you're going to be adding a row of widgets, then put all those widgets in their own sizer. Here's an example for adding rows of widgets:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.id = 1
        self.row_dict = {}

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        addBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Add")
        addBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onAdd)

        self.mainSizer.Add(addBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onAdd(self, event):
        """
        Add row of widgets
        """
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Test")
        removeBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Remove row", name=str(self.id))
        removeBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onRemove)

        self.row_dict[str(self.id)] = sizer

        self.id += 1

        sizer.Add(label, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(removeBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(sizer)
        self.mainSizer.Layout()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onRemove(self, event):
        """
        Remove row
        """
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        name = btn.GetName()
        print name
        print "removing => ", self.row_dict[name]
        sizer = self.row_dict[name]
        for child in sizer.GetChildren():
            widget = child.GetWindow()
            print widget
            sizer.Remove(widget)

        #self.mainSizer.Remove(self.row_dict[name])
        self.mainSizer.Layout()
        self.Layout()

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Add Widgets")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I haven't been able to get the remove method to work properly, but the add method works great. Hopefully this will help you get started at least.